# Scalar UDF in MS SQL Server Only Returns one Value in Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to use a scalar UDF like the one below to perform row by row operations (I am aware of the performance limitations of this).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[correctAbsenceLess25](@value varchar(4))
RETURNS decimal(3,1)
AS
BEGIN

    If (@value) = 'A'
        RETURN -1
    If ((TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3,1),@value)) >= 0.0 AND (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3,1),@value)) <= 25.0)
        RETURN @value

    RETURN CAST('Error happened here.' as decimal(3,1));

END
```

I then call the function from a query like this:

```
UPDATE assessmentData
SET assessmentData.weekReviewWk1 = dbo.correctAbsenceLess25(assessmentStaging.weekReviewWk1)
FROM assessmentStaging;
```

However, I only get -1 in the `assessmentData` table, despite there being a mix of values that satisfy both criteria and some values that should throw an error.

I know that it is a scalar UDF and returns one value, but it is meant to return one value for each value given to it by the query i.e. perform row by row operations and checks, isn't it?

Comment: What are the values for weekReviewWk1 column in assessmentStaging, also how are you joining the table assessmentData with assessmentStaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a varchar variable to the function and returning/updating with a decimal. You might want to consider changing your data types.

There is no relation between the tables for the update. You need to specify records that the UPDATE modifies. You could try a JOIN in your update to target a single record (or set of records) using some ID or combination of fields. Your UPDATE and FUNCTION would become something like the following:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[correctAbsenceLess25](@value varchar(4))
RETURNS varchar(4)
--RETURNS decimal(3,1)
AS
BEGIN
     If (@value) = 'A'
         RETURN '-1'
     If ((TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3,1),@value)) >= 0.0 AND (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3,1),@value)) <= 25.0)
         RETURN @value

       --RETURN CAST('Error happened here.' as decimal(3,1));
         RETURN 'Err';
END
```

And the tables/dummy data and UPDATE statement:

```
DROP TABLE assessmentStaging
CREATE TABLE assessmentStaging (
id int not null,
weekReviewWk1 varchar(4) not null
)

INSERT INTO assessmentStaging
VALUES
(1, 'A'),(2, '26'),(3, '25'),(4, '24'),(5, '2'),(6, '40'),(7, 'A')

DROP TABLE assessmentData
CREATE TABLE assessmentData (
id int not null,
weekReviewWk1 varchar(4) not null
)

INSERT INTO assessmentData
VALUES
(1, 'A'),(2, '26'),(3, '25'),(4, '24'),(5, '2'),(6, '40'),(7, 'A')

SELECT * FROM assessmentStaging

SELECT * FROM assessmentData

UPDATE  data
SET     data.weekReviewWk1 = dbo.correctAbsenceLess25(stage.weekReviewWk1)
FROM    assessmentData data
JOIN    assessmentStaging stage
ON      stage.id = data.id
```